# Ejabberd How to Add New User to Roster

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

This seems like a pretty simple question, but how do I essentially populate/create a user's roster so that I can show the list of a user's contacts in a client. I previously used Openfire were you could do this through the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using mnesia storage, you can add new users using the ejabberctl cli:
ejabberdctl register example_user_name example_host example_password